# Как дебажить удаленный сайт через xdebug в VS Code?

Tags: debian, php7, visual-studio-code, xdebug

В vs code поставил **remote ssh и remote ssh : explorer** 
в конфиге ssh пробую пробросить порт 9000 , по которому vs code будет слушать xdebug на сервере

```js
Host debug
    HostName y.y.y.y
    User web
    ForwardAgent yes
    DynamicForward 9000
    # RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698
```

далее подключаюсь к серверу, ставлю плагин x_debug, создается папка на сервере .vscode, в нем настройка для дебагера launh.json

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
         {
            "name": "VS",
            "type": "php",
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "port": 9000,
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "log":true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "/var/web/sites/namesiteY",
                "/app": "../"
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

На самом сервере с сайтом установил x_debug ([по этой инструкции](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php)) , добавил в php.ini эти настройки :

```
;XDEBUG START

zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so

[XDEBUG]

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = x.x.x.x
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = VS
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.force_display_errors = On


;XDEBUG END
```

В итоге пробую нажать start debug для простого тестового скрпита

```
$home = 1 + 4;

echo $home;


$value = 0;
if ($value == 0 ) {
    echo "TRUE";  // ТУТ BREAKPOINT
} else {
    echo "False"; // И ТУТ
}
```

ничего не происходит, переменные не записываются, в debug console появляется это :

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true }
```

пробовал с плагином для хрома и без, проверил слушает ли иде 9000 порт : 
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/090719/1A2n8TG0?a , вроде все ок
где я косячу?

***p.s 1***

в доках плагина xdebug для vs code есть пример мапинга :

```
// server -> local
"pathMappings": {
  "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/www",
  "/app": "${workspaceRoot}/app"
}
```

не совсем понятно относительно чего прописывать эти пути ? относительно папки .vscode?  нужно ли это в моем случае?

***p.s 2***

```
y.y.y.y - ip сервера с удаленным сайтом
x.x.x.x - мой статичный ip ( там где установлена ide)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На примере подключения к Vagrant. Домашнаяя система Xubuntu 18.04 гостевая ubuntu 16.04
Подключен плагин Remote SSH

Настройки `.ssh/config`

```
Host vagrant
    HostName 192.168.33.10
    User vagrant
    IdentityFile ~/projects/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Подключаемся, у нас слева внизу пишет `ssh:vagrant`

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_startup_errors = on
display_errors = on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=8014
xdebug.idekey=code
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

Ставим нужные экстеншены на удаленный сервер. В данном случае нужен php debug.
Перезагружаемся, пробуем проверить брейкпоинт.

Маппути в launch.json не трогаем. Почему? Мы получили следующую ситуацию: vscode подключился сам на удаленный сервер и теперь будет находится на удаленном комп. xdebug должен отправить данные не на твой айпишник, а на свой локальный, а его слушает наш vscode

А когда мы со своего компа хотим чтобы удаленный сервер нам отправлял данные через интернет, то пишем след настройки
Это в vscode

```
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 8014,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/vagrant": "${workspaceRoot}",
              }
        }
```

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.33.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port=8014
xdebug.idekey=code
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

А это в xdebug
idekey не обязательный, он вроде нужен, чтобы прописать в окружении (где работает код) ключ, который потом можно передавать через браузер.

Итого, самый удобный способ, это через ssh дебажить.